# How to inject EJB Bean in different modul in Stripes ActionBean method?

Tags: java, ejb, stripes

Im writing JavaEE application, which contains of three modules.
In web module I need to inject ejb bean (in Stripes action bean method), which is located in ejb module.

So i followed this tutorial 
http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Stripes+Injection+Enricher

My code goes like this>

```
@EJB
private CustomerServiceLocal customerService; //service layer for customer
```

and after deploying on GlassFish it returns following exception>

```
No EJB found in JNDI, tried the following names:
list of JNDI that it tried.
```

The bean is declared as follows>

```
@Stateless
@Local(value=CustomerServiceLocal.class)
@LocalBean
public class CustomerService implements CustomerServiceLocal {
```

interface>

```
@Local
public interface CustomerServiceLocal
```

I dont know what code could be relevant, so if I missed something just tell me what should I copied here.

So do you have any idea how to solve it ? How to set EJB Bean in different module in Stripes ActionBean method ?

It seems that stripes injection enricher is somehow wrongly configurated.

The problem is I need that service layer make work, since it is responsible for work with DB, and without it, I can just work with temporal local objects, which is useless.

Best regards,

OSiRiS